# Map Service Works in Flex, Won't Display using JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, map-service, arcgis-flex-viewer

As the title states, a map service published on my server displays and can be identified just fine when added to a web map in Viewer for Flex. I am slowly learning to use the API for JavaScript. My current JavaScript code works as intended when using a third-party map service for testing purposes. When I replace it with the service I published, it does not display the service. The rest of the map displays correctly, just not my service. I cannot figure out why it works in Flex, but not JavaScript. Any one run into this or have any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: Map service, dynamic. Arc 10.1, JS API 3.10

The service does display in the above example, and when you view it through the REST Services directory.

The error I'm getting is "Unable to draw graphic (geometry:null, symbol:null): null" ... but I am not finding any null geometry.

Comment: You should probably publish the JS code you use and what is the type of service you are trying to show (map/image and cached/dynamic). Software version and JS API version?

Comment: specifially, does your service display when substituted in a sample like this: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/map_dynamic.html

Comment: What Alex and John said, plus check out what errors your getting in the browser console along with any info on failed responses using fiddler/firebug/chrome developer tools.

Comment: I meant to add that I am using Feature Layer and not Dynamic Map Service Layer in the script. As stated in the original post, other services display fine as a Feature Layer. I tried a Dynamic Map Service Layer for my service and it still would not display, even though the service displays fine in other JS examples.